# Making a for loop in R in which the number of iterations is a reactive variable from UI input

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I am trying to create a ShinyApp in which the Mandelbrot Set is displayed as an image. What I want to be able to show is that the more iterations are performed, the greater the sharpness of the image. Hence, I have placed a slider input in order to increase or decrease the number of iterations.

When I try to replace `n <- 10` with `n <- input$iteraciones`

I get the following error:

```
Warning: Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext: Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
  61: stop
  60: .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext
  59: getCurrentContext
  55: .subset2(x, "impl")$get
  54: $.reactivevalues
  52: server [#11]
```

Here is my complete script:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Image
  plotOutput('mandelbrot'),
  
  # Slider iteraciones
  sliderInput('iteraciones','iteraciones',min=1,max=50,value=5)
)



server <- function(input, output){
  
  #Mandelbrot Set
  a <- seq(-2,2,0.003) #Componente real
  b <- seq(-1.5,1.5,0.003) #Componente imaginario
  c <- outer(a,b*1i, FUN="+") #matriz numeros complejos
  
  z <- matrix(0.0, nrow=length(a), ncol=length(b)) 
  k <- matrix(0.0, nrow=length(a), ncol=length(b))
  
  n <- input$iteraciones 
  
  for (rep in 1:n) { 
    for (i in 1:length(a)) { 
      for (j in 1:length(b)) { 
        if(Mod(z[i,j]) < 2 && k[i,j] < n) {
          z[i,j] <- z[i,j]^2 + c[i,j]
          k[i,j] <- k[i,j] + 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  # Mandelbrot Image
  output$mandelbrot <- renderPlot({image(a,b,k)})
  
}



shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I appreciate all corrections to my code, thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You need to make a reactive expression, have a look at [this tutorial](https://mastering-shiny.org/basic-reactivity.html#reactive-expressions-1)

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code that is in the server function really only runs once. If you want code to run in response to input, it needs to be reactive. Here's how you might change your code

```
server <- function(input, output){
  
  #Mandelbrot Set
  mbset <- reactive({
    a <- seq(-2,2,0.003) #Componente real
    b <- seq(-1.5,1.5,0.003) #Componente imaginario
    c <- outer(a,b*1i, FUN="+") #matriz numeros complejos
    
    z <- matrix(0.0, nrow=length(a), ncol=length(b)) 
    k <- matrix(0.0, nrow=length(a), ncol=length(b))
    
    n <- input$iteraciones 
    
    for (rep in 1:n) { 
      for (i in 1:length(a)) { 
        for (j in 1:length(b)) { 
          if(Mod(z[i,j]) < 2 && k[i,j] < n) {
            z[i,j] <- z[i,j]^2 + c[i,j]
            k[i,j] <- k[i,j] + 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
    image(a,b,k)
  })
  
  # Mandelbrot Image
  output$mandelbrot <- renderPlot(mbset())
}
```

This is a pretty core idea of Shiny. If you are new to Shiny, check out the [Reactive tutorials](https://rstudio.com/resources/shiny-dev-con-2016/) form the 2016 Shiny Dev Conference.